# rails 4 - stripe_event functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm using the Stripe payment service, with the `stripe` and `stripe_event` gems. So far so good-- they work great.

I want to use the `stripe_event` webhooks listener to do a bunch of actions. For example, when Stripe sends a webhook advising the application of a new subscription, I want to add that subscription to the `subscriptions` table, send an email to the new user, advise admins, etc.

In the (very scant) `stripe_event` [docs](https://github.com/integrallis/stripe_event) on github, they say to subscribe an object with the `call` method, and show the example as

```
class CustomerCreated
  def call(event)
    # Event handling
  end
end
```

However they don't show where this code lives (what file it would be placed in) or how it's invoked from `config/initializers/stripe.rb`.

Can someone provide a clear example of how to use these?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What I would do is make a new directory `app/stripe_handlers` and stick that code in a file named `customer_created.rb`. Any code in `app/` gets automagically loaded by Rails. You could also stick it somewhere in `lib/` but it wouldn't get autoloaded.

You would put your handler from your question in `app/stripe_handlers/customer_created.rb`, then in `config/initializers/stripe_event.rb` you would say something like:

`StripeEvent.configure do |events|
  events.subscribe 'customer.created', CustomerCreated.new
end`

When `StripeEvent` gets an event with type `customer.created` it will call the `call` method on the instance of `CustomerCreated` that you made in the initializer.

Comment: thanks for the idea. I did consider putting them in `lib/` and then using `require` but I wasn't sure what the standard practice is. I also don't know how to invoke the function from the `stripe.rb` class.

Comment: Once you've told `stripe_event` about the handler class it will automatically invoke the `call` method when it needs to. You don't have to do anything special there. I edited my answer to add a bigger example.

Comment: Thanks Pete-- this is what I ended up doing. However, I would prefer to use `/lib` just to minimize the required files loaded on each page. Is there a way to autoload a the `/lib/stripe_events/` directory so I don't have to require each individual class?

Comment: Yep! Inside `config/application.rb` add this line: `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/stripe_events)`

Comment: thanks, but that will load all `/lib/stripe_events` on every page of the site, which was what I was trying to avoid by using `/lib`, right?

Comment: Nope. Well, sort of. On production classes will only get loaded once, at start up time. On subsequent page loads Rails reuses everything.

Comment: This is a nice solution. But stripe has ~30 or more events. What do you do if you want to catch every event?

Comment: StripeEvent has support for prefix handlers. So if you want to handle all customer events, you can register a handler for `customer.`. You can also register one handler for all events by saying `events.all YourHandlerClass`.

Comment: @PeteKeen : Can we or should we add authentication to the stripe handlers?

Comment: @rAzOr StripeEvent will automatically authenticate events by throwing away everything that Stripe sends except the ID and retrieving the event via the API and your secret key. There's no reason to add any kind of authentication.

Comment: @PeteKeen: It's 2018 now and I wonder if the solutions outlined above are still considered best practice? If I remember correctly, something changed in Rails 5 regarding auto loading. I am facing the problem that in my Rails 5 app the `stripe_handlers` folder doesn't seem to get loaded sometimes. By the way, I also bought your book :-)